# How to start a process from windows service that keeps running after services exits

Tags: c#, process, windows-services

This is the scenario to accomplish:

- program A runs as a service
- program A instantiates a process object and uses that to start
  program B
- program A waits for 1 minute - program B is still running - program A
  closes the process object that was used to start/watch program B

The c# code at this point looks similar like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   using (Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\path\to\workingDirectory";
      startInfo.Filename = "ExternalAppEXE";

      process.StartInfo = startInfo;
      process.Start();
      process.WaitForExit(2000);

      if (!process.HasExited)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Process has not ended yet.");
      }
      process.close();      
    }
}
```

> question - when program A closes the process object will program B still be running?

Comment: Your question seems easy enough to answer with a simple test. Just start a process from the service, and then exit the service. Does the process stay alive?

Comment: I updated the question @JimMischel.  If I do this from visual studio lunching for example notepad.exe it does stay alive.  Will it happen with the service as well?

Comment: I don't know why you're asking me. It's easy enough to build a service with .NET and run the test yourself.

Comment: Thanks, my apologies, I didn't want to be rude.  I'm new with C#.  I found a way to test it.  Thanks for your comment.